# How to disable keystroke output in Zebra TC51

Tags: barcode-scanner

I'm working on android development in TC51 with DataWedge API and I want to send the scanned data to different TextView based on the scanning order. But the scanned data always output as keystrokes and always appear in the focused edit text view (which is not the one I target).

I've tried the config to disable the keystroke output through API, but it is not working.

```
Bundle ksConfig = new Bundle();
ksConfig.putString("PACKAGE_NAME", "KEYSTROKE");
ksConfig.putString("RESET_CONFIG", "true");
Bundle bParams = new Bundle();
bParams.putString("keystroke_output_enabled","false");
ksConfig.putBundle("PARAM_LIST", bParams);
Intent dwIntent = new Intent();
dwIntent.setAction("com.symbol.datawedge.api.ACTION");
dwIntent.putExtra("com.symbol.datawedge.api.SET_CONFIG", ksConfig);
cxt.sendBroadcast(dwIntent);
```

DataWedge API version: 6.8.50

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me, EXTRA_PROFILENAME is the name of datawedge profile:

```
    public void disableKeystrokeOutput() {

        Bundle configBundle = new Bundle();
        configBundle.putString("PROFILE_NAME", EXTRA_PROFILENAME);
        configBundle.putString("PROFILE_ENABLED","true");
        configBundle.putString("CONFIG_MODE","UPDATE");

        Bundle bConfig = new Bundle();

        bConfig.putString("PLUGIN_NAME", "KEYSTROKE");
        Bundle bParams = new Bundle();
        bParams.putString("keystroke_output_enabled","false");
        bConfig.putBundle("PARAM_LIST", bParams);

        configBundle.putBundle("PLUGIN_CONFIG", bConfig);

        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setAction("com.symbol.datawedge.api.ACTION");
        i.putExtra("com.symbol.datawedge.api.SET_CONFIG", configBundle);
        i.putExtra("SEND_RESULT", "true");
        i.putExtra("COMMAND_IDENTIFIER", "KEYSTROKE_API");
        this.sendBroadcast(i);
    }
```